# multiply or dividing doesn't works correctly when the second number is negative

Tags: calculator, division, negative-number, multiplication

im trying to write windows 7s calculator but i have problems just in multiply and divide. here im writing the codes that are connected to multiply so you can get the reason.

```
    double input1;
    double input2;
    double result;
    string amalgar;
```

amalgar means + or - or * or /

```
private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        input1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        textBox1.Clear();
        amalgar = "*";


    }
```

it was for * button.

this is for negativation button :

```
private void button20_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        input1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        input1 = input1 * (-1);
        textBox1.Text = input1.ToString();
    }
```

and this is for equal button:

```
input2 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
if (amalgar == "*")
        {
            result = (input1 * input2);
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
        }
```

here is some examples for results:

```
2*6=12      Right
 2*(-2)=4    Wrong
 (-2)*2=-4   R
 4*(-5)=25   W
 8*(-7)=49   W
 3*(-6)=36   W
 8/2=4       R
 8/(-2)=1    W
 8/(-3)=1    W
```

Comment: What language is this in? C#?

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you hit the negative button, you overwrite what you had in input1 with the negative of the contents of the textbox.

```
private void button20_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        input1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text); // These lines overwrite
        input1 = input1 * (-1);                   // anything in input1
        textBox1.Text = input1.ToString();
    }
```

So that when you go to the equals code, input 2 and input 1 are always the same number if the last thing you pressed was the negative button.

```
input2 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text); // this equals input1 if the last thing
                                          // you pressed was the negative button
if (amalgar == "*")
        { // ....
```

In `button20_Click` you need to modify the contents of textBox1 without overwriting input1. Something you could try is using a local variable to do all your calculations on:

```
double modifiedInput = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
modifiedInput = modifiedInput * (-1);
textBox1.Text = modifiedInput.ToString();
```

Comment: thanks dear.you post the answer while i was writing my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved it .it was an easy mistake.

the problem was in negativation button with i tried to multiply input1 by -1.

i have changed the code to :

```
input3 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            qarine = input3 * (-1);
            textBox1.Text = qarine.ToString();
```

in that button and some clauses in equal button :

```
else if (amalgar == "*")
        {
            if (input1 > 0 && input2 > 0)
            {
                result = (input1 * input2);
            }
            else if (input1 < 0 && input2 < 0)
            {
                result = (input1 * input2);
            }

            else if (input1 < 0 && input2 > 0)
            {
                result = (qarine * input2);
            }

            else if (input1 > 0 && input2 < 0)
            {
                result = (input1 * qarine);
            }

            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
        }
```